# SQL query to remove reversed charges

Tags: sql

I'm trying to solve a chargeback issue. Sample data provided below. I need to completely remove the charges that have been chargeback (UnitSold -1) from the results. The highlighted rows are all that should remain. I have tried using COUNT and SUM to try to get it to zero out or give me at least enough code to rule out what shouldn't be there, but have just ended up banging my head against the wall.

```
TABLE DATA
|OrderDate |CustomerID|ProductID|UnitsSold|TotalCharge|
|----------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|
| 1/14/2020|  12345   |  99496  |    -1   |  730.00   |
| 1/14/2020|  12345   |  99496  |     1   |  730.00   |
| 2/27/2020|  67890   |  99496  |     1   |  160.00   |
| 2/27/2020|  67890   |  99496  |     1   |  210.00   |
| 2/27/2020|  67890   |  99496  |    -1   |  210.00   |
|10/22/2020|  98754   |  99496  |     1   |  550.00   |
|----------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|


FINAL RESULTS
|OrderDate |CustomerID|ProductID|UnitsSold|TotalCharge|
|----------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|
| 2/27/2020|  67890   |  99496  |     1   |  160.00   |
|10/22/2020|  98754   |  99496  |     1   |  550.00   |
|----------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not link to an image of your data but instead copy it directly into the post (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it would be good if you added which DBMS you are using as this may influence the possible answers.

Comment: @buddemat, I tried to figure out how to do that the other day but had no luck. Thanks for sending the help link. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select date,customer_id,product_id,sum(unit_sold) as unit_solde,sum(unit_sold*unit_charge) as unit_charge 
from table
group by date,customer_id,product_id
having sum(unit_sold)>=1
```